# GDAL warning when importing GeoPandas

Tags: gdal, geopandas

When I `import geopandas` I get the follwing warning:

```
Warning 3: Cannot find header.dxf (GDAL_DATA is not defined)
Cannot find header.dxf (GDAL_DATA is not defined)
```

Though everything seems to be working correctly, I would really like to know what the reason for this warning is and how to solve it.

I installed GeoPandas on my Windows machine using Anaconda install (and conda-forge).

Package versions:
GeoPandas: 0.14.3
GDAL: 3.8.4

Comment: set GDAL_DATA=C:\gdal\data see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883445/how-to-fix-the-enviroment-variable-gdal-data-path-set - its setting the version of AutoCAD see https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-A85E8E67-27CD-4C59-BE61-4DC9FADBE74A

Comment: I recall having had these kind of issues, possibly linked to the environment not getting activated properly, in the past when I had multiple installations of anaconda/miniconda/miniforge on one computer. Could that be the case? Unistalling all installations and reinstalling one helped me back then, but if you have many environments this can be a pain...

Comment: I tried to do this as I had one other environment containing GeoPandas, however it didn´t solve the issue. However, I found a solution within the answer of Mapperz.

Answer (score 1):

Often the reason is that for some reason your environment is not in its best shape.

A good first thing to do is to make sure that you don't mix packages from different conda channels. I would try to create a new environment like this:

```
conda create -n geo
conda activate geo
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3.11 geopandas
```

Comment: I forgot to say, I already used conda-forge setting up my environment. I´ll update that in the question. I also tried setting up a new approach as in your answer but the result is the same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment of @Mapperz, I was able to resolve it.

By adding the following code the warning does not appear:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = os.path.join(f'{os.sep}'.join(sys.executable.split(os.sep)[:-1]), 'Library', 'share', 'gdal')
```